# How to insert multiple data in sqlite android studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sql-insert

hello im newbie in android studio, i have 2 tables DB, first table is budaya and second sejarah. When i try insert data to tables budaya using values put its work, but when i want to insert data to table sejarah the data it doesnt show up, please help me.

here is my bad code

```js
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    final static String DB_NAME = "db_budaya";

    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 8);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS budaya(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nama TEXT, kategori TEXT, deskripsi TEXT, img BLOB)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        
        String sql1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sejarah(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, materi TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql1);
        
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        // Budaya table
        values.put("_id", "1");
        values.put("nama", "Suhunan Jolopong");
        values.put("kategori", "Rumah Adat");
        values.put("deskripsi", "Suhunan Jolopong, yaitu bentuk bangunan yang atapnya (suhunan) memanjang, sering disebut suhunan panjang atau gagajahan. Bentuk Jolopong sendiri memiliki dua bidang atap. ");
        values.put("img", R.drawable.imv_rumahadat_joloponggagajahan);
        db.insert("budaya", "_id", values);
        
        ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();
        // Sejarah table
        values.put("_id", "1");
        values.put("materi", "Hello world");
        db.insert("sejarah", "_id", values1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS budaya");
        onCreate(db);
        
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sejarah");
        onCreate(db1);

    }

}
```

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: use room database instead of SQLiteOpenHelper i hope it will help to you!

Comment: You drop the table after you have inserted values. Also, what is `db1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You instantiate `values1` as the `ContentValues` object to use to insert the new row in     `sejarah` but you use `values` which contains the values for the table `budaya`.
Also there is no need to pass a value for the auto incremented column:

```
ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();
values1.put("materi", "Hello world");
db.insert("sejarah", null, values1);
```

Comment: So i must change values.put to values1.put, right?

Comment: @SmittyWerben yes and don't pass a value for `_id`.

Answer (score 0):

As of now I have only one doubt in your code. You can use below code snippet.

```
    ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();
    // Sejarah table
    // values.put("_id", "1"); // <- Comment it
    values.put("materi", "Hello world");
    db.insert("sejarah", "_id", values1);
```

Because, `values.put("_id", "1");` this line may be the issue, due to you have `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` So you don't have to set value implicitly.